# Button to make every table column visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I use the following code to toggle the visibility of an array of columns in a table (which uses the DataTables JQuery PlugIn)

```
function fnShowHide( iCols )
    {
    var i, iCol;
    var oTable = $('#statstable').dataTable();

    for (i = 0; i < iCols.length; i += 1)
        {
        iCol = iCols[i];
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
        }
    }
```

I would make it work like so...

```
<button id="button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide([0,4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]);">Simplify</a>
</button>
```

The problem is... If I have multiple buttons like this on a page, the columns get mixed up.

How can I make a new function that shows ALL columns, regardless of it's visibility, or even better, how can I make this button make everything visible, then turn off the ones in the array?

Thanks - this is probably simple, but I'm quite new to javascript.

Comment: As an aside, can't you replace the expression `bVis ? false : true` with simply `!bVis`?

Comment: Please also change `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide` to `<a href="#" onclick="return fnShowHide` and return false at the end of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having the following code:

```
<input id="myButton" value="Click Me!" />

$("#myButton").click(function () {
    showAllColumns();
});

function showAllColumns() {

    var i, iCol;
    var oTable = $('#statstable').dataTable();

    var length = /* get the number of columns */;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        iCol = i;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, true );
    }
}
```